# Node/MongoJS normalization query - how do I translate ID to name?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, relation, database-normalization

I'm fairly new to Mongo, and the documentation is still a little blurry for my understanding.

I'm working on a pharmacy app - where doctors are connected to practices. (medical practice) 
The details (name, address, etc.) of these practices can be changed at any given time, and so I cannot create the doctor in this format:

{ name: "Dr. John", practice: "Yellow Medical Centre" } - because if that name is changed, it will be a pain updating it everywhere.

**Now, my question is**, assuming that I am already inserting doctors with a `practice_id` field instead of a `practice_name` field - how do I resolve the `practice_id` into a `practice_name`, before sending it back to the client - *because they would like to see the doctor's practice name, not the ID of it.*

(I made a huge mess, initially, so I'll just leave the plain part here)

```
app.get('/doctors', function(req,res){
    db.doctors.find().forEach(function(err,doc){

    });
});
```

Am I *supposed* to loop through them all, or not? Mt goal is for each `Doctor's`->`practice_id` to actually contain `practice_name` - which obviously requires the assistence of the `db.practices` collection. But how do I make that translation in this stage? Or am I supposed to do it from the client-side controller?

Some guidance would be helpful, thanks.